# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, ado.net

am getting this error. like"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll" at `sda.fill(ds)` help me out please..

```
private void txtSearch02()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ItemCode,ItemName,PointsNeeded from tb_ItemRedemption where (ItemCode is null or ItemCode='" + txtkey2.Text.Trim() + "') or (ItemName is null or ItemName='" + txtkey2.Text.Trim() + "')", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //Session["ItemCode"] = dt;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    sda.Dispose();
    //con.Close();
    // Adding two columns
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("TotalPoints"); 
    //Caliculation
    txtPointsNeeded.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PointsNeeded"].ToString();        
    foreach (DataRow drdt in dt.Rows)
    {
        txtTotalPoints.Text = "";
        drdt["Quantity"]=txtQuantity.Text;
        drdt["TotalPoints"]=txtTotalPoints.Text;
    }
    //Caliculation
    txtGetQuantity.Text = txtQuantity.Text;        
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that is calling this function as well, could be an infinite loop.

Comment: This is only Code.And i am not getting idea whats it calling sir.

Comment: Try sending your connection with your SqlDataAdapter; new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con); Then remember closing the dataadapter. I don't think you need the con.Open() and Close() in this case either.

Comment: i have tried with that idea sir but am getting again error like CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @chrish549 that's not the overload you want - try `SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`

Comment: @D Stanly sir Still error coming ...